# How to create dynamic table row in sendgrid template

Tags: php

I want to send the email to the customer with the invoice number and multiple transactions.
but I can't generate multiple rows in sendgrid template. I have sent array data in a template but it doesn't generate multiple rows.

I want to know sendgrid template support dynamics row generate.

I have a template where I have 2 column and multiple rows the first column is product name which is -product- second column price which is -price-.
I have passed dynamics value for two column -product- and -price- but it's showing in two column array not generated dynamics value.

**Here is the snippet I am using:**

```
$mail->invoiceTamplate('X-SMTPAPI', '{"filters":{"templates":{"settings":{ "enable":1,"template_id":"test"}}},"sub":{--product--":["'.$product.'"],"--price--":["'.$price'"]}}');
```

Answer (score 1):

At last, I have found a solution for this situation. When you have passed a dynamics value for two or three whatever else you need to process before passing in a template.

Exam: I have a template where I have 2 column and multiple rows the first column is product name which is -product- second column price which is -price-. I have passed dynamics value for two column -product- and -price-. so we don't need to pass two value in the sendgird template we have just pass on a value in a template which value we have set all data as a string.

```
  <?php 
  $html = "<table><tr><th>product</th><th>price</th></tr>";
  foreach($datas as $data)
  {
  $html.="<tr><td>".$data['product']."</td><td>".$data['price']."</td></tr>"; 
  }
  $html .="</table>;

  $table = $html; 

  $mail->invoiceTamplate('X-SMTPAPI', '{"filters":{"templates":{"settings":{ "enable":1,"template_id":"test"}}},"sub":{"--table--":["'.$table'"]}}');
  ?>
```